# Android OnKeyListener

Tags: android, listener

Why I can't implement OnKeyListener with parameter View such as on [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) where parameters are **(View  v, int keyCode, KeyEvent  event)** I'm forced to use parameters (**DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)** but not the View as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the import statement at the top of your code and change it to the correct one.  they probably both have the same same but are in different packages.

Delete

> import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;

Add

> import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;